# AS3 Preloader Timing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I did the following

```
package classes 
{
// imports removed

public class Main extends MovieClip {

    // vars removed

    public function Main():void {

        trace('--> Main Function started ...');

        /**************************************
        Preloader
        **************************************/
        var preLoader:PreLoader = new PreLoader(); // init
        stage.addChild(preLoader); // to Stage
        stage.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,  preLoader.preloaderProgress); // calling the function

        doThis();
    }
}
```

With the PreLoader Class looking like this:

```
package classes  {

// imports removed

public class PreLoader extends MovieClip {

    public var totalBytes:uint;
    public var loadedBytes:uint;

    public function PreLoader() {
        trace('--> PRELOADER Started ...');
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedHandler);

        this.loaderBar.scaleX = 0;
    }

    private function addedHandler(e:Event):void {
        trace('Adding Preloader ...');
        totalBytes = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
        trace('PL: Total ' + totalBytes + ' / ' + loadedBytes);

        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedHandler);
        preloaderProgress(e);
    }

    public function preloaderProgress(e:Event):void {
        trace('Progress...');
        loadedBytes = this.stage.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
        this.loaderBar.scaleX = loadedBytes / totalBytes;
        this.loaderBar.alpha = 1 - this.loaderBar.scaleX;

        if (totalBytes == loadedBytes) {
            trace('Removing PreLoader ...');
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    }

}
```

}

**The Problem:** The Preloader is not displayed BEFORE the inital SWF-file has finished loading. Even all the tracing outputs start when the main movie is finished - i did some profiling on 'slow connections'.

If you wonder: doThis() is loading data from a xml-file, from here everything is fine, tracing outputs are at the right time (but too late at all :D)

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Maybe the question is: Is there a way to determine when the main movie is starting to load?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have any content other than the preloader on stage in the first frame.  Otherwise all that content will have to load before the preloader starts up.

Comment: Thanks! Same here: If the movie is empty, except the document class and the preloader class - how to you do that? Btw: the document-class is putting elements on the stage later on...

Comment: see this forum post - I think it explains what you are experiencing.
http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=197265

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in FlashIDE you have to put your preloader into the first frame. If you prefer to use another IDE you should use `Frame` metatag. Example:

**Main.as**

```
package com.sample.preloader
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Author
 */
[Frame(factoryClass="com.sample.preloader.Preloader")]
public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point
    }

}

}
```

**Preloader.as**

```
package com.sample.preloader
{
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Author
 */
public class Preloader extends MovieClip 
{

    public function Preloader() 
    {
        if (stage) {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        }
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);
        loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress);
        loaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);

        // TODO show loader
    }

    private function ioError(e:IOErrorEvent):void 
    {
        trace(e.text);
    }

    private function progress(e:ProgressEvent):void 
    {
        // TODO update loader
    }

    private function checkFrame(e:Event):void 
    {
        if (currentFrame == totalFrames) 
        {
            stop();
            loadingFinished();
        }
    }

    private function loadingFinished():void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);
        loaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress);
        loaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);

        // TODO hide loader

        startup();
    }

    private function startup():void 
    {
        var mainClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("com.sample.preloader.Main") as Class;
        addChild(new mainClass() as DisplayObject);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: thank you! i didn´t quite understand what you meant by "put your preloader into the first frame" as there is nothing in the movie expect the document class and the preloader class. Is there a way to put the document class in the second frame?? The init()-method was a very nice trick! thank you for that!

Comment: hello again. I altered the PreLoader.as and used it as document class for my flash-file - right? now i get an error: _Error #1065: Variable Main is not defined._ -  `var mainClass:Class = getDefinitionByName('classes.Main') as Class;` Did I miss something?

Comment: hello :) No, you have to use Main.as as document class.

Comment: Ok! `loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress);` throws a #1009 Error - when using `addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress);` there is no #1009 - but again the #1065: Var Main not defined - while the rest of the script is executed an display as intended.

Comment: it should be stage.loaderInfo